# Problematic database design causing performance issues

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-design, sql-server-2014, query-performance

I am designing a multi-module C#/SQL Server-based application.  My design is to hold all generic look up values in a table called `KeyTypeValues`.  This table is related to `KeyTypes` which defines what type of data it is.

For example:

```
oms.KeyTypes
------------
Id          INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
KeyTypeName VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
...

oms.KeyTypeValues
-----------------
Id                  INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
KeyTypeId           INT NOT NULL (FOREIGN KEY to oms.KeyTypes Id)
KeyTypeValueMeaning VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL
...
```

oms.KeyTypes sample data:

```
Id KeyTypeName         KeyTypeDescription
-- -----------         ------------------
1  RES_MFGS            Resource Manufacturers
2  RES_OWNERSHIP_TYPES Resource Ownership Types
...
```

oms.KeyTypeValues sample data:

```
Id KeyTypeId KeyTypeValueMeaning
-- --------- -------------------
1  1         Ford
2  1         Chevrolet
3  2         Owned
4  2         Leased
...
```

So the idea is that I don't have to create separate `Manufacturers`, `OwnershipType`, `Model`, etc. etc. tables as we don't really need any additional information about these values other than their value.  Currently I have about 88 already defined and the design has worked well for me.

I'm working on a problem query that is giving me performance issues when joining from a table called `res.ResourceItems`.  I have to join it onto the `KeyTypeValues` table 6 times for different lookups.

Part of `ResourceItems` definition:

```
res.ResourceItems
-----------------
Id               INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
OwnsershipTypeId INT NOT NULL
ManufacturerId   INT NOT NULL
...
```

If I eliminate my problem key type (`RES_OWNERSHIP_TYPES`), I can run it wide open and it pulls back ~112,000 rows with 70+ columns in about 17 seconds.  The performance isn't fantastic, but considering I'm having to join onto 9 additional tables, it is acceptable.  However, when I add the join to retrieve `RES_OWNERSHIP_TYPES`, the execution time jumps to 45 seconds.  The the `RES_OWNERSHIP_TYPES` key type only has 3 possible values at this point and `oms.KeyTypeValues` only has about 3,000 total records in it.  It will continue to grow slowly over time as we add more to the system being built.

I realize that pulling Ownership Types out and creating an `enum` instead would be a more efficient way to handle this as it is unlikely that we'll have anymore ownership types; however, I am concerned with the overall design where there is such a dramatic performance hit.

I do have Foreign Key relationships from `res.ResourceItems` to `oms.KeyTypeValues` for all the Id values.  I also have Non-Unique, Non-Clustered index setup on `oms.KeyTypeValues.Id` column.  I've rebuilt them to eliminate fragmentation.

As a test, I created separate `KeyTypes` and `KeyTypeValues` tables in my `res` schema and loaded just with `RES_OWNERSHIP_TYPES` values and joined to it, and the execution time went back to about 17 seconds.  I'd rather not carry this out as it sort of defeats my purpose and seems to be putting a band-aid on a bigger issue.

I cannot determine why there is such a big hit just with that join and was hoping someone might have insight into what I might be overlooking.  I'll be happy to share more of the database design if needed.

Comment: Consider using [covering indexes](http://www.dbadiaries.com/sql-server-covering-index-and-key-lookup/). Note that SQL Server 2005 and later versions support [included columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx) as well as composite indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If adding a join to a table with 3 records is impacting your performance that significantly, it means the query plan is changing dramatically with the addition of that join.

The quick and dirty thing to try is to run `sp_updatestats` one-time to see if that solves your problem (and I think it likely that it will).  This will tell SQL Server to update the statistics on all tables and indexes and help it make better choices with query plans.

The more thorough solution is to compare the execution plans of the two variations of the query to understand *why* performance is suffering.  This should shed light on how to improve performance.  I do not advise removing the table and going a code-only enum.  If things are working correctly, there should be no discernible performance difference in joining in that extra table.

Comment: I did both your and @FLICKER suggestion and both helped.  Simply running `sp_updatestats` had the biggest impact, getting back under 20 seconds.  Adding additional indexes and using subqueries shaved off another few seconds, so both queries are effectively the same now.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use `sub-query` instead of `JOIN`

Sometimes if lookup table is small (as your lookup table is), `sub-query` works faster than `JOIN`

However we don't have the actual data and don't have execution plan, so you should try different answers as suggestion and see which one works for you.

In case this did not work, try adding index on referencing fields (in addition to referenced fields).

BTW, I don't think your design is bad. I have seen such a lookup tables in many different systems.

Comment: Thanks - I wish I could mark both yours and @Tim as answers; however, updating the stats seemed to be the biggest culprit.  I experimented with subqueries and additonal indexes and I was able to shave off a few extra seconds.  Thanks for the comment on the design - yeah I've used this type of design in different systems and it's quite good, I think.

Comment: Keeping statistics up-to-date is always a good thing. Thanks for up-vote :)